# can function pointer point to member function of STL container

Tags: function, pointers, stl

For example, 
if I have

```
deque<int> a;
```

and I want to use a function pointer to `a.front()` , `a.back()` and `a.push_front()`， `a.push_back()`,  can I accomplish that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to member functions are a different type of function pointer than regular pointers, due to needing to pass `this`. The best solution is to implement a wrapper function as such:

```
template<typename T>
T deque_front(std::deque<T> *q) {
  return q->front();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a (non-static) member function, you need an object to call it on (as well as the parameters of the function). This is implemented by having the member function take a (hidden)
extra parameter, `this` (effectively).

If you're using c++11 you can write a lambda to do this, or use `std::bind` to bind an instance of a deque and a member function together.